# Customizing UItabBar Item order

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I want to change the order of UITabBar items.
Then when I log in again, the order should be maintained.

How this can be done? Can anybody help me? I've wasted a whole day to implement this.

Comment: Did you create your tabBar programmatically or using a nib file?

Comment: do you want to change the order of the tabs after restarting the app or during use and reset it when restarting the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rearranging Tab Bar Controller Order in StoryBoard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662700/rearranging-tab-bar-controller-order-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to do it programmatically it should be fairly simple:
Persist the index of each view and then add each view to an array in the same order doing load:

```
  //construct your view controllers somehow and add them to an array in the order you want them to be:
    [myArr addObject:viewCon1];
    [myArr addObject:viewCon3];
    [myArr addObject:viewCon2];
```

construct your tabbar   using your array

```
_tabControl = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[_tabControl setViewControllers:myArr  animated:YES];
```